# VisualStudio2012 how to set default file description comments?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I set in VisualStudio that when creating a new file MyHeader.h that it will automatically put some comments in the beginning of the file like when it was created and by who?

Comment: Ugh, just don't. There's not a lot more frustrating than pointless comments at the top of *every* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do that in two ways.

- [Modify Default Template](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/)
- [Using Macro](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/05/add-document-header-for-files-automatically-in-visual-studio/)

It seems like using with Macro is more convenience to me. (*by adding macro in context menu*)